# Can't send e-mail via Gmail with Java

Tags: java, email

I can't send an e-mail with java code via Gmail.

CODE:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class b {

    public static void sendMessage(String to, String from, String subject, String text){



        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");


        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            String mfrom = "fromemail";
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", mfrom, "fromemailpassword");
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I get the error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b3sm24500496wiw.22 - gsmtp
```

I am trying to send an e-mail from a Gmail account to a Gmail accout without success. I need to do this for my business e-mail to send out newsletters ect.

EDIT:

I changed a section of code to this:

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   //make it true
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //make it true
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
        //Authentication is needed use your gmail user and password"smtp.gmail.com"
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("email@gmail.com", "password");
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
```

And now I get the exception:
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Comment: did you try a google search first? many net examples of this. see [FAQ] on need to search first

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaMail smtp properties (for STARTTLS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592112/javamail-smtp-properties-for-starttls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your properties are contradictory.

You are setting the SMTP port to `587`, which (according to [this page](http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm)) is the server port for SMTP over TLS.  But then you are setting `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` to `false`.

Naturally the Google SMTP server is confused ... and it tells you that it was expecting the client to send a STARTTLS command.

Solutions:

- Change the `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` property to `true`.
- Alternatively, change the `mail.smtp.port` property to `465` (the SSL port)

You don't have the option of using "vanilla" SMTP ... which is a good thing if you care about securing your email traffic.

---

According to [this resource](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/), you also need to enable authentication.  (The page has extensive Java example code ...)

Answer (score 0):

starttls should be `true`.

means add :

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

then post me that working or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The response code 530 means **access denied**

The accompanying message indicates that gmail is expecting a STARTTLS.
Try with

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Although it may need more properties to work properly

Besides: non-secure SMTP is always a bad idea unless its local.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
 properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
 properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   //make it true
 properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //make it true
 properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
 //Authentication is needed use your gmail user and password"smtp.gmail.com"
 Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
     return new PasswordAuthentication("yourGmailUserName", "yourGmailpassword");
     }
 };
 Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
```