# Connect to outlook.office365.com with java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

How can I connect to a outlook.office365.com host using IMAPS (whis SSL connection) protocol ?
with a shared folder account?

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(p, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

    store.connect("outlook.office365.com",993,"ACCOUNT NAME","PASSWORD");
```

Comment: Does that code not work? What happens when you try?

Comment: it gives me this error Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592112/javamail-smtp-properties-for-starttls .

Comment: No , i use imaps not smtp

Comment: It doesn't like how you're logging in.  Can you log in with an IMAP client as expected, such as thunderbird?

Comment: Does [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/6369118f-7dee-4728-ac1c-a0c706b3d290/office-365-exchange-online-how-to-access-a-shared-mailbox-using-thunderbird-or-other-imap-client?forum=onlineservicesexchange) help?

Comment: Did you found solution, to connect to office 365 using imaps protocol?